# Setting style.background as a var doesn't work

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I modified this working [Javascript code](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval_clearinterval2) by setting style.background as var "x" and it doesn't toggle anymore. Where is the problem?

```
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(setColor, 300);
 
function setColor() {
/* This commented-out code works.
  var x = document.body;
  x.style.backgroundColor = x.style.backgroundColor == "yellow" ? "pink" : "yellow";
  */
  var x = document.body.style.backgroundColor;  // not working
  x = x == "yellow" ? "pink" : "yellow";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Well yeah, you're not setting `document.body.style.backgroundColor = something;`, you're setting `x = something`...

Comment: What is `console.log(x)`? You should do some debugging.

Answer (score 3):

That's because in the original code:

```js
function setColor() {
  var x = document.body;
  x.style.backgroundColor = x.style.backgroundColor == "yellow" ? "pink" : "yellow";
}
```

x is a reference of document.body, nevertheless, in your code, when you do:

```js
x = x == "yellow" ? "pink" : "yellow";
```

x is not equal to a reference of document.body anymore, now it is a string, either pink or yellow. So, x will not change the html because it is only a string variable.

If you want the code to work, you need to add this code behind x declaration.

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = x
```

Comment: Thanks, you pointed out my bug: x is a "backgroundColor" string, cannot be used to reference the body. @Andy The console.log(x) always showed only string "yellow" whereas the working one showed <body style="background-color: yellow;"> and <body style="background-color: pink;"> toggling.

Comment: I shouldn't have assigned a value to x. I could have done like `var x = document.body.style;
  x.backgroundColor = x.backgroundColor == "yellow" ? "pink" : "yellow";`

Comment: The console.log(x) shows CSS2Properties { "background-color" → "pink" } and CSS2Properties { "background-color" → "yellow" }.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning a value to variable "x", not `document.body.style.backgroundColor`, don't store it in a variable.

```html
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(setColor, 300);
 
function setColor() {
  var x = document.body.style.backgroundColor; 
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = x == "yellow" ? "pink" : "yellow";
}
</script>
```